# how to insert corretly my picture in css?

Tags: css, image, sass, path

i have a problem to insert my picture, i have a 404 error, though i thought that my path was correct. 
my files are :

> - main-menu
>
>   - phone.png
>   - _menu.scss

in my file _menu.scss, i have the next code :

```
 .phone {
  background-image: url(phone.png);
}
```

.phone is the name of my class. i work with drupal and twig.

thank you for you help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

When added as background in div, 'height' and 'width' must be added for the background image to appear.

it is don't showing:

```css
 .phone {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/300);
}
```

```html
<div class="phone"></div>
```

but it is showing:

```css
 .phone {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/300);
   height:300px;
   width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="phone"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your response but even with adding height and width, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

If your file tree is right, then all you need to do is add a width and a length.  You are not telling the browser how tall and wide to make the phone, so it will show nothing.

```css
 .phone {
  background-image: url(phone.png);
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="phone"></div>
```

I don't have your phone.png, but it should be like so.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

There are two ways of importing an image.
1. Using HTML  tag.
2. Using CSS background.

> When using css version, don't forget background-size and background-position.

#### Example:

```css
.image {
  background: url('path/to/img.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain; /*This scales the image accoding to the div*/
  background-position: center center; /*positions the image in the center*/
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="path/to/img.png" />

<div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: thank you but even this solution, it doesn't work. maybe i must write the absolute path ?

Comment: Is the image placed in the same folder as the index.html / main.css file? if so then you don't need to define a path. Otherwise, try '../' to move back and '/' to move forward into your folders. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Also absolute path can have issues when loading the project on the server. Not the best practice.

Comment: always no. i don't really know. the two files are in the same folder, so i write my code "img src="phone.png" ... and error, error and error. i don't understand

Comment: Another thing I notice is, that in the code you have put up there, you’re saying: url(phone.png). It’s missing the “”. So try url(“phone.png”). Let me know if that was the issue or not.

Comment: i have tried too. Maybe is it a problem with drupal ?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but i have always the same problem:
my TWIG code:

```
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="phone">
  </div>
```

and my SASS code:

```
.phone {
  background: url('phone.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain; /*This scales the image accoding to the div*/
  background-position: center; /*positions the image in the center*/
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
}
```

and my files are always the same too:

- main-menu

  - phone.png
  - menu.scss

i have always the 404 error
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:  `./phone.png`.

```
.phone {
  background: url('./phone.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain; /*This scales the image accoding to the div*/
  background-position: center; /*positions the image in the center*/
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
}
```